# How to handle license for third-party packages?

Tags: license, python

I've created a Python package, and it contains another package written by a third-party:

```
my_pkg/
  |- vendor
  |    |- vendoredFoo (MIT license)
  |
 ...
```

How to handle the license of `vendoredFoo`, which is distributed under MIT license?
I want to opensource `my_pkg` as MIT or Apache license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer converted from third-party comments:

Have you read [Are we liable for license problems posed by transitive OSS libraries](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7246/are-we-liable-for-license-problems-posed-by-transitive-oss-libraries)?  However, if what you are including is MIT licensed, then meeting the requirements of that license should be very simple.

In other words I believe the answer to your question about how to handle the license of vendoredFoo is the same as any other MIT licensed package. If you copy the code, you have to abide by the license.